# Generating function over primes in an arithmetic progression

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, generating-functions

Given a newform $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a(n)q^n$. Is the generating function
$$
\sum_{p\equiv a\pmod{m}}a(p)q^p
$$
over the primes $p\equiv a\pmod{m}$ still a modular form? Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Absolutely not. That's a terrible sum.

Comment: @Satan'sMinion I agree. I explained this in a bit more detail below. The easiest would be to say that $\sum_p a(p)/p^s$ is not an entire function, but I don't see a succint way to show that.

Comment: Probably it's also easy to see the Hecke algebra orbit would have to be infinite dimensional.

Comment: If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! How can I accept your answer? Please let me know.

Answer (score 7):

It is not a modular form. To see this, let $f(q)$ be the initial modular form, and let us assume (without loss of generality) that $a(1)=1$. Let $k$ denote the weight of $f(q)$. The Rankin-Selberg $L$-function $L(s,f\times\tilde f)$ has a simple pole at $s=1$, hence
$$-\frac{L'(s,f\times\tilde f)}{L(s,f\times\tilde f)}\sim\frac{1}{s-1},\qquad s\to 1.$$
This implies the following variant of the prime number theorem:
$$\sum_{p\leq x}|a(p)|^2\sim x^k/\log x,\qquad x\to\infty.$$
However, if $\sum_p a(p)q^p$ were a modular form of weight $\ell$, then Rankin-Selberg theory would give that for some $c\geq 0$,
$$\sum_{p\leq x}|a(p)|^2\sim c x^\ell,\qquad x\to\infty,$$
contradicting the previous asymptotic formula.

Comment: Nice quick argument!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insightful justification! It’s really helpful! Appreciated.